# Пройтись по единичкам от левого края до правого

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Полный текст задачи:
1. Создать квадратную динамическую матрицу заполненую нулями и единицами размером N на N (N больше 1000);
2. Сделать процент заполнения единицами;
3. Вырезать фрагмент из матрицы, пригоден для вывода на экран (дальше работаем только с вырезаным фрагментом);
4. Вывести таблицу координат всех единичек;
5. Возможность вставить и удалить единицу;

И то, с чем я не могу справиться: проверить, можно ли после всех этих процедур пройтись цепочкой по единицам от левого края до правого (где начать и закончить - значения не имеет)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    int matr_x;
    int naprocente;

    cout << "Введите размер матрицы х: " << endl;
    while (true) {
        cin >> matr_x;
        if (matr_x < 1001) {
            cout << "Размер матрицы должен быть больше 1000" << endl;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    int **matrix = new int *[matr_x];
    for (int i = 0; i < matr_x; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new int[matr_x];
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < matr_x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matr_x; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    cout << endl;

    int nmatr_x;

    cout << "Введите размер фрагмента, который нужно вырезать: " << endl;
    while (true) {
        cin >> nmatr_x;
        if (nmatr_x > matr_x) {
            cout << "Новая матрица не может быть больше предыдущей:" << endl;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }


    int **newmatrix = new int *[nmatr_x];
    for (int i = 0; i < nmatr_x; i++) {
        newmatrix[i] = new int[nmatr_x];
    }

    cout << "Введите процент заполнения ненулевыми элементами: ";
    cin >> naprocente;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < nmatr_x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nmatr_x; j++) {

            if (matrix[i][j] > naprocente) {
                newmatrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
            else {
                newmatrix[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nmatr_x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nmatr_x; j++) {
            cout << newmatrix[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < nmatr_x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nmatr_x; j++) {
            if (newmatrix[i][j] == 1) {
                cout << "x = " << i << " y = " << j << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    char chs;
    cout << "Вставить ненулевой элемент? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> chs;

    if (chs == 'y') {
        int coord_x, coord_y;

        while (true) {
            char chs_1;
            cout << "Введите координаты: " << endl << "введите x: ";
            cin >> coord_x;
            cout << "введите y: ";
            cin >> coord_y;

            if (newmatrix[coord_x][coord_y] == 1) {
                cout << "Сдесь уже есть ненулевой элемент" << endl;
            }
            else {
                newmatrix[coord_x][coord_y] = 1;
                cout << "Вставить еще один? (y/n)" << endl;
                cin >> chs;
                if (chs == 'n') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nmatr_x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nmatr_x; j++) {
                cout << newmatrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    char chs_2;
    cout << "Удалить ненулевой элемент? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> chs_2;

    if (chs_2 == 'y') {
        int coord_x1, coord_y1;

        while (true) {
            char chs_1;
            cout << "Введите координаты: " << endl << "введите x: ";
            cin >> coord_x1;
            cout << "введите y: ";
            cin >> coord_y1;

            if (newmatrix[coord_x1][coord_y1] == 0) {
                cout << "Сдесь уже есть нулевой элемент" << endl;
            }
            else {
                newmatrix[coord_x1][coord_y1] = 0;
                cout << "Удалить еще один? (y/n)" << endl;
                cin >> chs;
                if (chs == 'n') {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nmatr_x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nmatr_x; j++) {
                cout << newmatrix[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matr_x; i++)
    {
        delete[] matrix[i];
    }
    delete[] matrix;

    for (int i = 0; i < nmatr_x; i++)
    {
        delete[] newmatrix[i];
    }
    delete[] newmatrix;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, стоит сократить количество кода. И описать больше саму проблему и место, где она возникает.

Comment: Код - это полностью готовое решение кроме последнего пункта. Я тупо не знаю как так сделать. Щас картинку сделаю, чтобы было понятно, что мне надо

Comment: Все, я сделал картинку, что мне примерно нужно

Comment: Любой поисковый алгоритм (поиск в ширину или поиск в глубину) по соседним единичкам даст вам ответ на вопрос о том, можно ли пройти от края до края.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`проверить, можно ли после всех этих процедур пройтись цепочкой по единицам от левого края до правого (где начать и закончить - значения не имеет)`

Нужно сделать так. Создать структуру со следующими полями:

```
struct Cell 
{
    int row, col; // индексы клетки
    std::stack<Cell> neighbors; // Соседние единички (клетки с единичным значением)
}
```

Для каждой текущей клеточки (с единичкой), при движении слева-направо, проверяете наличие соседей с единицей, если таковых больше одной, то добавляете всех соседей в стек neighbors (не включая той, из который вы пришли!), а уже саму текущую клетку добавляете в стек узлов (с ветвлениями). Выбираете очередного соседа и продолжаете движение.

Если у очередной клетки нет соседей и вы еще не достигли правого края, то берете из стека ветвлений последнюю сохраненную клеточку, а у нее из стека соседей вынимаете очередную ветку и идете далее уже по ней.

И так до тех пор, пока, либо вы не выйдете на правый край (левая картинка), либо стек ветвлений не опустеет, что будет означать, что прохода нет (правая картинка)